# How can implement captcha Using android

Tags: android

Can any one give some suggestions to implement captcha in android

Comment: You're worried about your Android being used by androids?

Answer (score 8):

A little bit of shameless self-promotion, but I recently had this same question, and after combing through StackOverflow.com realized that all of the solutions out there are Remote API based (which would require my simple app to require Internet permissions), and either were super difficult to implement on Android, or were limited by use based numbers and you could not get that number raised.

### [So I started a project, and put it on GitHub, Click here](https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha)

Current features are limited, but I hope they will grow with the open-source community:

1. Simple Text Captcha, editable length.
2. Simple Math Captcha, editable math operators.
3. The biggest feature of all is ease of use!

Comment: No Shame, all I can see great effort.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this project, they have a some android's examples

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/captcha/downloads

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/captcha/documentation

or maybe use this

http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/

to get some ideas.