# Source code for captcha in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can implement captcha Using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666019/how-can-implement-captcha-using-android)

Anyone Does implement captcha in android. please share source code for this in android or any link that having example would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Sample project is [here](https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha)

Also look out [references](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/)